# Using (...'s) in phrases

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Which of the following phrases are correct?

"Faulhaber formula" or "Faulhaber's formula"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Faulhaber formula" on its own is not good, because it's not grammatical. "The Faulhaber formula" is at least grammatical.

The question is then: should you put "the" before the name, or should you use a possessive? Usage varies, and sometimes you may see both forms.

I see that Wikipedia's article is named "Faulhaber's formula", so I would go with that.

Comment: If there are one or two other general forms of this Faulhaber's formula, we write: "Generalized Faulhaber formula" and not "Generalized Faulhaber's formula"?

Comment: British English often puts apostrophes where American English does not, for example the condition Down's syndrome is called Down syndrome in the US.